# What tweets aren't tweets?

Tags: json, twitter

I've grabbed a load of tweets using the [`sample`](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/sample) api. That's great. I know how to 'chuck' the tweets that are actually notifications of a tweet being deleted, but there lots of other cases, and who knows when another will be added? The cases are infact mentioned [here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/platform-objects/tweets):

> Tweets can be embedded, replied to, favorited, unfavorited, retweeted, unretweeted and deleted.

How do I know though that I've got a POTO (Plain Old Twitter Objects) and not a delete, favourite etc. ?

*Is there a standard process that could identify this?* The `Delete` tweet for instance starts with `{"delete":{....` so I can match for that as a string or try and look it up as a key (on JSON-Simple, it's done like [so](http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/wiki/DecodingExamples#Example_5_-_Stoppable_SAX-like_content_handler)). What would be nice if all the POTOs started
`{"tweet":{....` then I could pick them out, not have to discard anything that wasn't a POTO(needing a check for every single non-POTO).

I could just use the key checker to find *every* key that I need, and hope that it's relevant and correct (for instance both a the tweet body and the tweeter/user has an `id`, unless it's a delete then it's a `id` and `user_id`. To get both you need to go into the `entities`). But if I'm using *[Storm](https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm/wiki)* (and I am going to be eventually) I may end up plugging a [bolt](https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm/wiki/Tutorial#bolt) on later on, I then have to go back and change my checks.

So, is there a simple way to distinguish a tweet that's a tweet (POTO) and not something else?

Comment: Presumably, every tweet will have a `text` field, and I don't see why a "pseudotweet" would have a `text` field. So, can you use the presence of a `text` field as an indicator of whether it's a real tweet or not?

Comment: I could, but I'm not certain that means it will have the other key's I'm after from the JSON, or that say I would never encounter a `{"text":"Twitter is going down for an hour,"official_tweet":yes"}` say, from the twitter people...